# ObjectStateEntry.Delete Method Marks entity as Deleted - But before or After?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

In the definiton of ObjectStateEntry.Delete Method

MSDN says:

```
"Marks an entity as deleted."
```

But does it mean it deletes it first and only then after it marks it as DELETED?
Or it marks it first and then it deletes the entry from the Db?

Answer (score 2):

The ObjectStateManager takes all the Informations about your changes to the entities.
So when you call myContext.Delete(myEntity) your Entity will be marked as deleted in the Objectstatemanger. But at this time it is not deleted.

It will be deleted, when you call myContext.SaveChanges();

Comment: To be more precise - when you call `SaveChanges` the entry is deleted physically from the database and detached from the context. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Changes to DB are applied only when Context.SaveChanges() method is called.
So, the entity marked as "Deleted" only in EF entities cache.